# Wrong validation error on a django modelform field when passed through clean method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, validation

Model and ModelForm in django project are defined like this :

```
class Consumption(models.Model):
    date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    product_name=models.ForeignKey(Stock,to_field='product_name')
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
    customer=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name

class ConsumptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Consumption

    def clean_quantity(self):
        cleaned_data=self.cleaned_data
        product=cleaned_data.get("product_name")
        quantity=int(cleaned_data.get('quantity'))
        stock=Stock.objects.get(product_name=product)
        if quantity > stock.quantity:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough stock")
        return cleaned_data
```

where Stock class contains product name which serves as Foreign Key to Consumption and and whose quantity should be greater than consumption quantity.

Now the problem is when I enter submit to ConsumptionForm . It gives me error on quantity field as this field must be an integer even after when I am providing it an integer.

What can be the reason of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning the whole `cleaned_data` dictionary from the `clean_quantity` method, rather than just the value of `quantity`.

Answer (score 2):

You won't need to typecast cleaned_data.get('quantity') to `int`. Django's to_python() method on the form base class will do that for you. All forms will try to convert their values to Python values as part of the validation process.

I don't see anything in your clean_quantity() method that would make me think that it won't work, although you're not showing your `Stock` class so we can see what type of field stock.quantity is.

My advice would be to write a unit test for this form and view method to ensure you're getting the correct values. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/

If you're not in a habit of writing unit tests, now is a great time to start. They can really save you a lot of time.